# Forbidden 403 apache2 no Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, unix

Bom este é o erro que estou tendo com o meu apache. Mudei o meu diretório do apache para: `/media/marcelo/Arquivos/Google Drive/localhost` e este diretório tem 777 de permissão.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Segue abaixo as duas ultimos linhas do log do apache2

```
::1 - - [09/May/2017:19:26:28 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/56.0.2924.76 Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [09/May/2017:19:26:29 -0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 511 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/56.0.2924.76 Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36"
```

A foto da pasta que tem permissão `777`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a configuração do apache2.conf

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at );
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a 
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a 
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.

    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied



    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

#estava /var/www/

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted


#
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#

    Require all denied



#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Segue o arquivo `/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf`(único arquivo)

```
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com
    #ESTAVA ______ /var/www/html

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/media/marcelo/Arquivos/Google Drive/localhost"

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Poste por favor a configuração do apache

Comment: @luislhl apache2.conf ?

Comment: O que eu queria era a configuração do domínio que está dando erro. De acordo com essa configuração que você postou, deveria ser um arquivo dentro da pasta sites-enabled.

Comment: @luislhl Atualizei a pergunta e adicionei o arquivo desejado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de exibir erro de permissão e depois o erro de não processar os scripts php via Apache aparentemente é causado por alguma edição errada sua, **ou mais** provavelmente por você ter instalado algo manualmente ou nem ter chegado a instalar o PHP de fato.

Sistemas como Ubuntu e Debian se estiverem usando os repositórios oficiais (do `apt`) raramente irão causar algum problema assim, presumou ou que você instalou manualmente mesmo ou que você editou o `sources.list`, claro que também tem a possibilidade de ter tentado instalar o PHP7 que geralmente não esta nos repositórios oficiais.

Você mencionou que usou o comando `apt-get install lampp`, vou ser sincero, ao menos nos repositórios oficiais tal pacote `lampp` não existe, isto deve ser de outra fonte, não sendo fonte oficial então não posso lhe oferecer uma resposta em base dela, mas posso lhe explicar como instalar o Apache + PHP + mysql de modo mais comuns em distros baseadas em Ubuntu.

Primeiro de tudo:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Instalando o Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Instalando PHP7 e 5.6

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.1
```

Se quiser instalar apenas o 5.6:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

Ou apenas o 7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-mysql php-gettext php7.1-mbstring libapache2-mod-php7.1
```

Para alternar entre o PHP7.1 e o 5.6 use os comando a seguir (se tiver ambos instalados):

- Usar PHP 7.1

  ```
  sudo a2dismod php5.6
  sudo a2enmod php7.1
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```
- Usar PHP 5.6

  ```
  sudo a2dismod php7.1
  sudo a2enmod php5.6
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

Pronto não é necessário configurar nada no Apache, isto é feito automaticamente, então basta mudar as permissões da pasta `/etc/www/` (ou mudar o proprietário) e então colocar os seus scripts `php` dentro desta pasta.

**É importante que note** que o php.ini usado pelo Apache muda de localização dependendo da versão que estiver usando do `php.ini`, pode procurar a localização usado um script assim:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

A página gerada se aberta via Apache vai lhe informar a localização correta.

### Xampp como alternativa

Isto tudo que mostrei é uma instalação um tanto quanto básica, se deseja ter algo como um painel e algumas ferramentas extras existe um pacote chamado *Xampp*, mas que não esta nos repositórios oficiais do Ubuntu (creio eu), ele pode ser instalado facilmente após baixar do site https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html

Pode-se usar um `wget` também:

```
wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.30/xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-1-installer.run
```

E depois do download execute assim:

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-1-installer.run
```

Se deseja usar o 7.1 eles também possuem na página https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html

Comment: Tem como alterar a localização pelo `php.ini`? Eu sempre uso o `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: Entendi, sou iniciante no linux, to aprendendo linha de comando agora, e nem sei direito o que é link simbólico(vou estudar), mas caso você queira deixar uma fonte(site) pra eu aprender isso eu fico feliz. Você tem mais experiência nisso do que eu.

Comment: Eu estava querendo fazer tudo pela linha de comando sabe, sem usar gráfico, pra ficar gravado na mente também. Mas no caso então cara, eu tenho de fazer o link simbólico no php.ini ou no  meu diretório www `/var/www/html` ?

Comment: Eu quero que os meus websites fiquem localizados no Google Drive, ou no MEGA, para quando eu estiver usando o Windows 7 ou Ubuntu, eu possa usá-los em qualquer lugar, entede?

Comment: Local do meu php.ini: `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`  
Pretendo inserir os meus websites em: `/home/marcelo/MEGA/localhost`

Comment: Tente digitar isto `ln -s /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini /home/marcelo/MEGA/localhost/php.ini` e depois tente acessar pelo Windows como você citou, se falha ao abrir então vou explicar como mudar a localização =)

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme o que você me ensinou pra mim é curioso, porque estou acostumado a fazer a troca de diretórios como ensina aqui: http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/alterar-pasta-padrao-do-xampp , pelo apache. E isso que você me ensinou de colocar o php.ini no diretório almejado não funcionou, o que pode ter ocorrido?  
Obs: só tentei no linux ainda